# Mining in Ether Wallet, Then Tansfer to BTC, Cash, or...?

Tags: mining, wallets

Thanks to the community.
I started mining Ether through the wallet,
What do i do with the Coins now?
Is there a place i can sell or transfer from ether wallet to BTC or something...?
Im lost please assist...
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options,

1. You can send them to an exchange, where you can sell them for btc or trade them for other altcoins. You can also store your eth there, but that is not recommended.
2. You can keep them, in which case you maintain ownership of them at an address on the Ethereum blockchain, where only you have access to them via your private key.

Comment: thanks any suggested exchanges... coinbase sucks... tried already

Comment: poloniex, kraken, bittrex to name a few.